# google drive java api error 400 when changing file owner

Tags: java, google-drive-api

Im trying to change file owner, from writer to owner but I'm still getting:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
 {
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Bad Request",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Bad Request"
 }
```

And here's some part of source code:

```
//getting writer permission
Permission permission = service.permissions().get(fileId, permToChange.get(j)).execute();
permission.setRole("owner");

service.permissions().update(fileId, permToChange.get(j), permission).setTransferOwnership(true).execute();
```

Both accounts current owner and new owner has same domain.
I was trying delete writer account, add new one and change ownership too but always got same result.